# Splash won't render all contents of page

Tags: splash-screen, scrapy-splash, splash-js-render

I am using [Splash](http://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) v2.3.2 and I am trying to render a [page](http://www.sothebysrealty.com/eng/sales/detail/180-l-2096-ft332f/sandow-lakes-ranch-rockdale-tx-76567) but it is not rendering everything. It won't render images or dynamically loaded content.

I am using my http://localhost:8050/ with script:

```
function main(splash)
  local url = splash.args.url
  assert(splash:go(url))
  assert(splash:wait(10))
  return {
    html = splash:html(),
    png = splash:png(),
    har = splash:har(),
  }
end
```

Here is a browser rendering:
[image: browser rendering]

Here is a screenshot of the Splash rendering:
[image: Splash rendering]

I have tried to change the wait time and also tried to allow plugins. None of this will work. I am assuming that the dynamically loaded content is being restricted but I am unsure. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is with localStorage - site uses it, but Splash uses Private Mode by default, and this disabls localStorage. To fix it, disable private mode (see [here](http://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#how-do-i-disable-private-mode)). This script works for me (Splash 3.0):

```
function main(splash)
  splash.private_mode_enabled = false
  local url = splash.args.url
  assert(splash:go(url))
  assert(splash:wait(10))
  return {
    html = splash:html(),
    png = splash:png(),
    har = splash:har(),
  }
end
```

See also: http://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#website-is-not-rendered-correctly

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you are trying to scrape property description text. In your code you have just added splash:wait(10), My suggestion is you should try and implement wait for a specific css element. In you case, **span#listingpropertydescription**.
You can write a function to wait for this particular element and then return the html page.

**Note** you can find a sample wait-for-element code in   http://localhost:8050/

Hope this will help you