# Splash is not loading javascript properly for crawling a website (scrapy-splash)

Tags: scrapy, splash-screen

I am having difficulty debugging why Splash is unable to load the javascript properly for this website: https://www.bigc.co.th/2000003703081.html

I have referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44915719/splash-wont-render-all-contents-of-page) answer to disable Splash from running in private mode and also other solutions [here in the docs](https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#website-is-not-rendered-correctly), such as increasing wait time and setting user agent.

However, the website is still loading as though without JS on Splash, as seen in this picture below
[image]

I am currently debugging why the website is not loading properly for the purpose of incorporating this with scrapy-splash code.

Here is my current script. Thank you for your time and assistance in advance!

```
function main(splash, args)
  splash:set_user_agent('Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.61 Safari/537.36')
  splash.private_mode_enabled = false
  splash:set_viewport_full()
  splash:go{url=args.url}
  assert(splash:wait(1))
  return {
    html = splash:html(),
    png = splash:png(),
    har = splash:har(),
  }
end
```